# Rolle's theorem, such that $f'(c)=2c$

Tags: real-analysis

We have that the function $f: \mathbb R \xrightarrow{}\mathbb R$ is differentiable and satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.

I need to use Rolle's Theorem to show that there exits $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=2c$.

I am unsure how to proceed considering we do not have $f(a)=f(b)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$. We know that $g(0)=g(1)$ and the question is now equivalent to finding $x$ such that $$f'(c)=2c\iff g'(c)=0,$$ which is of course just Rolle's.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$g(x)=f(x)-x^2 \implies g(0)=0, g(1)=0$$
Apply, Rolle's Th. on $g(x)$ this means $g'(c)=f'(c)-2c=0$ where $c\in(0,1).$